# There's an eclipse folder in my trash that I can't delete. Is it okay if I try to forcefully delete it?

Tags: command-line, java, eclipse, delete, trash

I'm new to Ubuntu and programming and to this forum (first post!). So I'm usually very careful about everything I do, because I'm so afraid of making a mistake and breaking something beyond repair. So here's the thing:

I've recently started learning Java and installed eclipse Oxygen on my Ubuntu 16 (32 bits). A few days ago I noticed that there's a folder named "eclipse" in my trash can that won't disappear even when I empty the trash. I tried removing it using the GUI (right click, remove), but an error message followed, telling me this: `"Failed to delete the item from the trash"`.

I wonder if it's okay to try to forcefully delete the eclipse folder (using the command `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/filename`, as I've seen in other posts in this forum), or if I should just leave it there. I mean, maybe it's part of how eclipse works, a way to retrieve deleted projects or something...

So, I just want to know if it's okay to try deleting it with this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/
```

Comment: The files in Trash has nothing to do with system performance. If this file had some sort of effects on *how eclipse works*, eclipse must have shown some symptoms. Just go ahead and delete it. You might need sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sometimes root trash ends up in your local Trash bin so you will need

  `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/`

or

```
sudo chown -R username ~/.local/share/Trash
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

- You can also find the info about these  in

  `/home/user/.local/share/Trash/info/*.trashinfo`
- No harm in force delete files or folders in trash if you are sure that these were not deleted by mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to delete the folder in trash through the GUI after typing this command `sudo chown -R username ~/.local/share/Trash` :)